Can't load Nobara installed alongside Windows and Ububtu
I had windows and Ubuntu installed and tried to install Nobara. After installation I restarted the device and couldn't see Nobara in dual load window. These are the only options:
Ubuntu
Advanced options for ububtu
Windows boot manager
UEFI Fireware Settings

I installed boot-repair on Ubuntu but still can't see the option to load Nobara.
grub.cfg:
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=10
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if [ ${grub_platform} != pc ]; then
      set linux_gfx_mode=keep
    elif hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-27-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-27-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.0-27-generic-advanced-9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-27-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.0-27-generic-recovery-9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.0-27-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-27-generic root=UUID=9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-27-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-18-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.0-18-generic-advanced-9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.0-18-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic root=UUID=9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 6.5.0-18-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-6.5.0-18-generic-recovery-9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 6.5.0-18-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic root=UUID=9492172d-0be6-43ed-81b5-cf9791031ac4 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-B6AE-1017' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  B6AE-1017
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root B6AE-1017
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###
### END /etc/grub.d/35_fwupd ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

How to show Nobara in dual boot window?

Installing a new OS in a multi-boot scenario may - but not necessarily does - change the boot order. Sometimes changing to new OS' bootloader is the intended result, many time it isn't. In this case it's up to you. In this case it shows Ubuntu's Grub is still the default. And, of course, it's unaware of the newly installed Nobara so you have to boot Ubuntu and run os-prober and update-grub. It won't be automatic, ever. Follow instructions here: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/grub-doesnt-detect-windows-linux-distros-fix

Boot Repair is not necessary in this situation and if used incorrectly it can create additional problems and solve nothing. Boot Repair is excellent for one thing though, and one thing only in this case, that is to produce a summary report of your system. You may want to do that - instead of applying any fix - and post the resulting link here so we can take a look at it. What you posted is pretty much irrelevant.
